# Photoshop how to Tile an image into bigger multiple layer image

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, layers

How can you tile a single image into tiled multiple layers in a bigger image?

Let's say you have 30x32 image, the new image you would want to have 3x2 tile, thus the new image would be 90x64. However, there should still be 6 layers in this new image.

To give a more specific example, if you are Andy Warhol and have a single image of a Campbell's soup can, you would like to tile it into a bigger image with multiple soup cans. Afterwards, you want to do some adjustments to individual soup cans separately.

Currently, I am just copy pasting original image into new blank image with a grid and dragging each new layer into appropriate slot by hand. Very time consuming. :)

This is on Windows XP with Photoshop CS3 Extended, but will appreciate any solutions.

EDIT: What I am looking for is something similar to Create Tiled Clones ability in Inkscape

Comment: You could most probably just make an Action which is editable, so that you can define the X and Y size of the tile image.

Comment: Making an Action is what I ended up doing, this is good enough for the time being. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CS5 Extended has multi-layer fill. If you create a texture with your tile (probably want to run a 50% offset filter, too) you should be good to go. I don't know if you are running this revision, but it might help. If you're running an older version, I believe gIMP also has multi-layer fill for textures, you should be able to perform this step in gIMP and then pop it back into PS without any deprecation.

Answer (score 1):

Most top ranked answers on the web(not SU) currently suggest manually making copies and moving them, the same thing I do currently, and rather silly for larger tiles. :)

So far the closest answer I've found is at: http://www.ehow.com/how_5844112_tile-photo-photoshop.html
This method alas did not work for me, I saw it tile in preview, but not in image.

Meanwhile, i will keep searching for a better solution...in the worst case one must be able to write a macro for this.

EDIT: found another method from 2004: http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/photoshop-basics/aligning-layers.33.html  Again, I am failing, this time at the distribution step, the linked layers do not get distributed evenly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a direct answer i know, so sorry if its not useful:

This is totally simple if you have InDesign; one linked photoshop, multiple instances = all instances update with any changes made to the photoshop file.